# Reactによるcsvの出力形式について

Tags: reactjs

Reactで以下のような機能を実装しようとしています．

HTML View

＜表の行数を指定するプルダウンリスト＞

| セル１ | セル2 | セル３ | セル４ | セル5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| １ | ２ | データ１ | データ２ | データ３ |
| ２ | ３ | データ４ | データ５ | データ６ |

上記のようなtable要素を生成しています．tableの行数は，プルダウンリストで指定し，動的に変化します．

このtableに入力された値を，csvで出力してEXCELで展開した際に，以下のような形式で表示されるようにしたいと考えています．

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| データ１ | データ４ |
| データ２ | データ５ |
| データ３ | データ６ |
| 1→2 | 2→3 |

現状，tableの並びでcsv出力は出来ているのですが，上記の形式で並び替えが出来ていません．
ご教授頂けたら幸いです．

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import saveAs from 'file-saver';
import './App.css';
import { encode } from 'iconv-lite'; // 追加

function App() {
  const [element, setElement] = useState(1);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(element + 1);
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([...Array(rows)].map(() => ['', '', '', '', '']));
  const [popupMessage, setPopupMessage] = useState('');

  const handleChangeElement = (e) => {
    const newElement = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setElement(newElement);
  };

  const handleCellValueChange = (e, rowIndex, colIndex) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    // 正規表現を使用して半角数字のみを許可する
    const isNumber = /^\d*$/.test(value);
    if (isNumber) {
      const newTableData = [...tableData];
      newTableData[rowIndex][colIndex] = value;
      setTableData(newTableData);
    }
  };

  const handleChangeCell = (e, rowIndex, colIndex) => {
    const newData = [...tableData];
    newData[rowIndex][colIndex] = e.target.value;
    setTableData(newData);
  };

  const constructCSVData = () => {
    const csvRows = tableData.map((row) => {
      const concatenatedValue = `${row[0]}→${row[1]}`;
      const formattedRow = [concatenatedValue, ...row.slice(2)];
      return formattedRow.map((cell) => `"${cell}"`).join(',');
    });
    return csvRows.join('\n');
  };



  const handleExportCSV = () => {
    let hasEmptyFields = false;
    const emptyFields = [];

    tableData.slice(2).forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
      row.slice(2, 5).forEach((cell, colIndex) => {
        if (!cell) {
          hasEmptyFields = true;
          emptyFields.push(`行 ${rowIndex + 3} 列 ${colIndex + 3}`);
        }
      });
    });

    if (hasEmptyFields) {
      const message = `未入力項目があります: ${emptyFields.join(', ')}`;
      setPopupMessage(message);
      alert(message);
      return;
    }

    const csvContent = constructCSVData();
    const encodedContent = encode(csvContent, 'Shift_JIS'); // 文字エンコーディングをShift_JISに変更
    const csvData = new Blob([encodedContent], { type: 'text/csv;charset=Shift_JIS' }); // 文字エンコーディングをShift_JISに指定
    saveAs(csvData, 'data.csv');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setRows(element + 1);
    setTableData([...Array(element + 1)].map(() => ['', '', '', '', '']));
  }, [element]);

  return (
    <div>
      正答結線数を入力して下さい．
      <select name="element" value={element} onChange={handleChangeElement}>
        {[...Array(100).keys()].map((i) => (
          <option key={i} value={i + 1}>
            {i + 1}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      {/*行の生成*/}
      <p>数値は半角で入力して下さい．</p>
      <table border="1">
        {[...Array(rows).keys()].map((i, index) => (
          <tr key={i} style={index === 0 ? { backgroundColor: 'gray' } : {}}>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                disabled={index === 0}
                placeholder={index === 0 ? '何番から' : ''}
                value={tableData[i][0]}
                onChange={(e) => handleCellValueChange(e, i, 0)} // 入力値の検証を行う
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                disabled={index === 0}
                placeholder={index === 0 ? '何番へ' : ''}
                value={tableData[i][1]}
                onChange={(e) => handleCellValueChange(e, i, 1)} // 入力値の検証を行う
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              {index === 0 ? (
                '分野'
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={`field${i}1`}
                    name={`field${i}`}
                    value="同分野"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeCell(e, i, 2)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`field${i}1`}>同分野</label>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={`field${i}2`}
                    name={`field${i}`}
                    value="別分野"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeCell(e, i, 2)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`field${i}2`}>別分野</label>
                </div>
              )}
            </td>
            <td>
              {index === 0 ? (
                '記述'
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={`description${i}1`}
                    name={`description${i}`}
                    value="記述有り"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeCell(e, i, 3)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`description${i}1`}>記述有り</label>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={`description${i}2`}
                    name={`description${i}`}
                    value="記述なし"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeCell(e, i, 3)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`description${i}2`}>記述なし</label>
                </div>
              )}
            </td>
            <td>
              {index === 0 ? (
                '認知'
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={`knowledge${i}1`}
                    name={`knowledge${i}`}
                    value="知識"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeCell(e, i, 4)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`knowledge${i}1`}>知識</label>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={`knowledge${i}2`}
                    name={`knowledge${i}`}
                    value="解釈"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeCell(e, i, 4)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`knowledge${i}2`}>解釈</label>
                  <label htmlFor={`knowledge${i}3`}>分析</label>

                </div>
              )}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>

      {/* 追加機能: CSV出力ボタン */}
      <button onClick={handleExportCSV}>CSVでマトリクスを出力</button>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```